# WSO2 IS 5.1.0 as OAuth/OIDC IdP response with different claims on UserInfo endpoint

Tags: json, curl, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

Anyone know why if I make a call to /userinfo endpoint I obtain different JSON response? Specifically:

- When I make a call with `curl` from command line, like `$curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 2bcea7cc9d7e4b63fd2257aa31116512" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid` I obtain as response the JSON: `{"sub":"asela","name":"asela","preferred_username":"asela","given_name":"asela","family_name":"asela"}`
- If I make the call with a java client (a library that implement the Authorization Code Flow), when the client make the /userinfo call I have as response a JSON like `{"sub":"asela@carbon"}` without all other claims.

The claims for the service defined in WSO2 IS are the default ones. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this and got the same issue that you have faced. As I have mentioned in my previous comment, the issue occurs due to the claim mapping issue. Normally we get the user's attributes from the “http://wso2.org/claims” dialect. But when we call to OpenID userInfo endpoint, it will provide the user's attributes from “http://wso2.org/oidc/claim”. But all the claims in  http://wso2.org/claims are not defined in  http://wso2.org/oidc/claim. (Ex:Mobile, Address, Organization). So we have to define those required claims on  http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect, if it is not defined. 
You can check this claims from Identity Server Management console. To do this, Log into ManagementConsole > Main > List (under Claims) 
Then you can go though the two claim dialects and add required claims to  http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect.
 To add new claim, Goto ManagementConsile > Main > Add(under Claims) > Add new claim. See the attached screen shot of  defining a sample claim. Here you need to map the exact Mapped Attribute & Claim Uri with the http://wso2.org/claims.
[image]
Hope this will helpful.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Shanaka, I've check in my `claim-config.xml`, but I see that the **"http://wso2.org/oidc/claim"** is well defined and already contains the claims that I receive as Json response when I call **/userinfo** endpoint with `curl`. It's possible that when I make the Auth Code Flow with java client the **/userinfo** endpoint response with a claim not defined in `claim-config.xml` ? This because in `claim-config.xml` I found only 1 definition for **"Subject/sub"** claim, in **"http://wso2.org/oidc/claim"** dialect.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IS normally returns the claims that are configured under the “http://wso2.org/oidc/claim” claim dialect. But the claim in the response should return normally. So make sure you have defined claim values in the user's profile. 
 You can follow [1] & [2] for more details about this. Still you couldn't get the correct response, please attached your SP configurations and claim configurations for further analyze.

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/09/openid-connect-support-with-resource-owner-password-grant-type/
 
[2] http://shanakaweerasinghe.blogspot.com/2016/01/get-user-profile-for-oauth-token-using.html

Comment: I verify @Shanaka, but the claims defined under `http://wso2.org/oidc/claim` are the ones I received in Json with **curl** client, my question is why if I make the call with the java client I obtain a different set of claims (only one, the **sub**) and the values for this claim are different changing the clients.

Comment: Hi giovanni, Sometimes this will be fixed, if we map http://wso2.org/oidc/claim with (default claims)http://wso2.org/claim.  I'll check this and update you ASAP.